# scikit-bio python module not getting installed on windows 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, skbio

`Scikit-bio` package is not getting installed. I have numpy 1.9.1. I tried installing from command prompt

> C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install
>
> C:/Users/mgi14-9419/Downloads/scikit-bio-0.4.0.tar.gz

I am getting the following error
[image: enter link description here]

Error Trace

```
C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install C:/Users/mgi14-9419/Downloads/scikit-bio-0.4.0.t ar.gz 
You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 7.1.2 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command. 
Processing c:\users\mgi14-9419\downloads\scikit-bio-0.4.0.tar.gz 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", 
line 1182, in do_open h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers) File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", 
line 1088, in request self._send_request(method, url, body,
```

Comment: please copy-paste all text-based information into code blocks instead of attaching images. That said, are you connected to the internet?

Comment: C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install C:/Users/mgi14-9419/Downloads/scikit-bio-0.4.0.t
ar.gz
You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Processing c:\users\mgi14-9419\downloads\scikit-bio-0.4.0.tar.gz
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1182, in do_open
        h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1088, in request
        self._send_request(method, url, body,

Comment: You can use the [edit] button below the tag line to update your question and add additional information. Comments are not well suited for amounts of output or code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scikit-bio is not yet supported nor installable on Windows. We have plans to add Windows support in an upcoming release (tentatively 0.5.0, scheduled for early 2016).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a workaround for Windows10 here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34276863/4275222, but you have to install [Anaconda's Python 3.5](https://3230d63b5fc54e62148e-c95ac804525aac4b6dba79b00b39d1d3.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/Anaconda3-2.4.1-Windows-x86_64.exe). It should work in Windows 7.