# How to find dissimilarity matrix (Plant communities) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, skbio

I have a plant community matrix as numpy array where rows are species and columns are communities

```
species 1,2,3   [[  0  13   2   0  11   0  12   5   0   0]    
   species 4,5,6    [  0  97   1   5 117   0  64  24  58   3]
   species 7,8,9    [  0   0   0   0   0   0  11   3   5   0]
   species 10,11,12 [  0  13   6   0   0   0  11   8   0   1]]
```

I want to calculate dissimilarity matrix. I tried installing python package scikit-bio but Im getting the error

```
error: command 'D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\B
IN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I installed ecopy module. When I import ecopy, I'm getting the error 'invalid syntax -ecopy.regression'

```
from .nls import nls
from .isoregress import isotonic
```

How to fix the above problems? Or is there any other module in python which I can use?

Comment: According to SciKit-Bio, they don't officially support Windows, and since no binary installer is available, you might have issues on a Windows system:
https://github.com/biocore/scikit-bio/issues/941

Comment: which python version are you using

Comment: I'm using Python 3.4

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh is correct, scikit-bio does not yet support nor install on Windows (see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33898789/3776794)